# How to prevent links in iOS webapp from opening in a new Safari-tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, safari

I'm creating an html application for iPads. I add the webapp to the homescreen using the "favorite" option. However, after I do this, every (internal) URL opens in a new safari tab. How do I prevent this? At the moment it is impossible to use my navigation which directs to other html files.

I aready found this code. Hower i get an error "undefined" on every url.

```
$( document ).on( "click", "a", function( event ){   
    page.event.preventDefault();   
    time.location.href = $( event.target ).attr( "href" );
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a `page` and `time` variables, which don't seem to be defined anywhere.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

As simple as that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution to my question!